# Listen to text in browse

Tags: python, browser, automation, screen-scraping

I am wondering if and how it is possible to 'listen to' the text that is in my browser window.

I am specifically NOT looking to scrape websites in the sense that I want to crawl them for information, I am just interested in interacting with an arbitrary page that makes my browser output text.

## Example

1. Suppose I am asking a question on Stack Overflow.
2. By the time I type a title of 'Listen to text in browser' the suggestions appear, one of them contains plain text 'Listen to browser request'
3. As soon as the word 'request' is on my screen, the browser will get shut down and I order a pizza

## What would a good solution look like

- I want to be able to do this for practically any website that somehow makes my computer show simple text. Ideally without having knowledge of how the text is generated.
- I want this to be somewhat fast, subsecond should be possible
- I do not want to hit the website or its api's, just want to use the information that is already on my screen.

I am not too picky about the OS and browser requirements.

I can also imagine there may be corner cases wher it is hard (perhaps text is shown as a picture, or perhaps parts of a sentence are actually spread across multiple textboxes that are just displayed to eachother). For now I just wonder how this can be done for a simple page.

Bonus points if it could even capture text from the field in which I am typing myself, so I can scald myself when I am about to say something stupid.

## What have I come up with so far

I am in general confident that I can process the text once I get it into a tool, however the main challenge is on how one can listen to the browser.

- I tried looking at the source code, but that does not appear to contain this dynamic text
- Perhaps there is a steraming API on the browser itself, that can stream out changes?
- Perhaps there is a way to grab all text from a browser, perhaps 10x per second or so
- Using the normal scraping solutions are completely not what I want, so I do not want to fire a request to the webserver 10x per second.
- In the worst case, I suppose we could use screen capture software, followed by text recognition, but I really hope there is something more elegant
- I suppose there may be automation/testing software that can do this. That would be an answer but something lightweight (e.g. a python library) would be nicest.

I have tried searching but did not find any solution, or even the question. Presumably I am using the wrong words.

Comment: You can use `Selenium` with [`get_attribute('value')`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/get-value-of-an-input-box-using-selenium-python). And wrap it in a `while True` that breaks once the conditions appear that make you want to order pizza.

Comment: This seems to solve the extra case for the field where I type myself. Do not hesitate to post it as an answer, especially if there is also a way to get the text that 'magically' appears